# Add List<DateTime> values inside a List<T>

Tags: c#, list, datetime

This might be kind of Tricky. Basically I've got a class that looks like this:

```
class Timer
{
    public string boss { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> spawnTimes { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Runtime { get; set; }
    public BossPriority priority { get; set; }

}
```

As you can see, I want to add a list of DateTimes in my object. So I've created a list that looks like this:

```
List<Timer> bosses = new List<Timer>();
```

I was hoping that I could do something similar to this, to add the DateTimes:

```
bosses.Add(new Timer { boss = "Tequatl", priority = BossPriority.HardCore, spanTimes = {  DateTime.ParseExact("07:00 +0000", "hh:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) } });
```

Unfortunately, that is giving me a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.

Doing it like this, doesn't make a difference either :(

```
Timer boss = new Timer();
DateTime t1 = DateTime.ParseExact("07:00 +0000", "hh:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime t2 = DateTime.ParseExact("11:30 +0000", "hh:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
boss.spawnTimes.AddRange(new List<DateTime> { t1, t2 });
```

Do I really have do .Add() on every DateTime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your NRE is caused by the fact you're not initializing `Timer.spawnTimes`.

You can save on typing if you initialize the class as part of the default constructor:

```
public class Timer {

    public List<DateTime> SpawnTimes { get; private set; }
    ...

    public Timer() {
        this.SpawnTimes = new List<DateTime>();
    }

}
```

Another option is to have an overloaded constructor that accepts `params` arguments:

```
public class Timer {

    public List<DateTime> SpawnTimes { get; private set; }
    ...

    public Timer() {
        this.SpawnTimes = new List<DateTime>();
    }

    public Timer(String boss, /*String runtime,*/ BossPriority priority, params String[] spawnTimes) : this() {

        this.Boss = boss;
//      this.Runtime = TimeSpan.Parse( runtime );
        this.Priority = priority;

        foreach(String time in spawnTimes) {

            this.SpawnTimes.Add( DateTime.ParseExact( time, "HH:mm" ) );
        }

    }
}
```

This is used in practice like so:

```
bosses.Add( new Timer("Tequat1", BossPriority.HardCore, "07:00 +0000" ) );
bosses.Add( new Timer("Tequat2", BossPriority.Nightmare, "01:00 +0000", "01:30 +0000" ) );
bosses.Add( new Timer("Tequat3", BossPriority.UltraViolence, "12:00 +0000" ) );
```

#### Also: FxCop/StyleCop time!

- Types (like classes) should be `PascalCase`
- Public members should also be `PascalCase` (unlike in Java where they're `camelCase`)

  - e.g. `public BossPriority priority` should be `public BossPriority Priority`
- Collection members should not be exposed through mutable properties (i.e. use `private set` instead of `set` (implied public)
- Public collection members should be `Collection<T>` or `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` or `T[]`

Comment: This is definitely my preferred option. This has the extra benefit in that if a `Timer` is constructed without explicitly constructing/assigning a `List<DateTime>` object, you don't have to deal with `null` references later. That is, `var t = new Timer(); t.SpawnTimes.Add(...);` is ok. Furthermore, you can confidently iterate on any `Timer` instance without having to perform a `null` check first. Finally, it makes your code simpler because you don't have to duplicate the `List<DateTime>` construction in _every single place_ you instantiate a `Timer`.

Comment: @GrantWinney: No, the `spawnTimes = { DateTime.... }` syntax will call the _Add_ method for each item on the `List` that was assigned during construction. This will not overwrite the instance of `SpawnTimes`. EDIT: It will only overwrite if you have `spawnTimes = new List<DateTime> { DateTime.Parse...}`.

Comment: @GrantWinney: Yeah, it's a bit buried in the documentation. An example of this in the [C# 3.0 Overview on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx), section "26.4.2 Collection Initializers". I _think_ the relevant declaration of the behaviour is in that same page, section 26.4: `A member initializer that specifies a collection initializer after the equals sign is an initialization of an embedded collection. Instead of assigning a new collection to the field or property, the elements given in the initializer are added to the collection referenced by the field or property.`

Answer (score 2):

You're close... you just forgot to declare a new instance.

Add `new[]` and then cast the the array to a `List`:

```
bosses.Add(new Timer { boss = "Tequatl", priority = BossPriority.HardCore,
    spawnTimes = new[] { DateTime.ParseExact("07:00 +0000", "hh:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) }.ToList() });
```

Comment: If you're going to do it this way, better off just having `new List<DateTime> { DateTime.ParseExact(....) }` rather than creating an array then throwing it out to create a `List` on top of it. EDIT: Also, this isn't "casting" the array to a list; it's creating a new list with the elements copied over.

Comment: Yeah, I just checked it out as well, it also working perfectly ^^. I will have to mark that one instead, sorry :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
spanTimes = new List<DateTime>{  DateTime.ParseExact("07:00 +0000", "hh:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) }
```

Basically, initialise a new list with the values you desire using List Initializer syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
bosses.Add(new Timer { boss = "Tequatl", priority = BossPriority.HardCore, spanTimes = new List<DateTime> {  DateTime.ParseExact("07:00 +0000", "hh:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) } });
```

you will have to `new` your `spawnTimes`

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the spawnTimes collection before using it

```
boss.spawnTimes = new List<DateTime>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close but need to include the List instantiation. Try

```
bosses.Add(new Timer { boss = "Tequatl", priority = BossPriority.HardCore, spanTimes = new List<DateTime>{ DateTime.ParseExact("07:00 +0000", "hh:mm zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) } });
```